# Input aparecer com dois números após a vírgula

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Eu tenho este html, que trago de um float:

```
 <input asp-for="Frete" name="Frete" onKeyPress="return(MascaraMoeda(this,'.',',',event))" class="form-control" />
```

Gostaria que quando trouxesse os dados do banco aparecesse o valor desta forma 0,00 e não assim 0.
Se o número é preenchido com 82,50, ele aparece dessa forma 82,5 e queria que ele aparecesse assim 82,50, como posso proceder, já tentei assim e não funciona:

```
ValorTotalPedido = float.Parse(pedidoFornecedor.ValorTotalPedido.ToString("N2")),
```

Comment: não seria uma alternativa exibir a _string_ (que você já formata corretamente) e o _input_ ter uma máscara numérica?

Comment: @rLinhares eu tenho uma função que formata, porém só na hora que o usuário digita, no evento `onKeyPress`

Comment: uma alternativa é você chamar esta função js após carregar a página (no fim do _ready()_); de qualquer forma, sempre preferi usar `onblur` ao invés do `onkeypress` por conta dos _ctrl+c ctrl+v_, não sei se seria o seu caso

Comment: @rLinhares no caso eu trago os dados do banco mesmo. Então preciso que ao ser chamada, seja formatado os campos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa que o seu campo que será apresentado seja uma `string`:

```
string valorTotalPedido = float.Parse(pedidoFornecedor.ValorTotalPedido.ToString("N2"));
```

Ou então, adicione na sua ViewModel o seguinte `DataAnnotation` para o campo `float`:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public float ValorTotalPedido { get; set; }
```

Comment: Perfeito, utilizei a segunda opção, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Faz assim:

```
ValorTotalPedido = float.Parse(pedidoFornecedor.ValorTotalPedido.ToString("0.00##"))
```

Aqui um fiddle funcionando: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RoVORC

Comment: Infelizmente desta forma não funcionou.

Comment: fiz um fiddle funcionando o format

Comment: O campo está formatado com vírgula , e não com ponto.

Comment: `.Replace('.',',')` não resolve?

Comment: Eu já fiz desta forma, e ele sempre retorna o valor assim `382,8` e não assim `382,80`, se eu faço assim `("0,00##")` trocando o ponto, pela vírgula, ele arredonda o valor para 383